# How to get sender email, photo in page conversations/messages{message}? Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, messenger

I'm accessing page conversations and their messages using this reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v8.0/conversation

My steps are:

```
api = facebook.GraphAPI(pageAccess)
args = {'fields': 'message,from,id'}  #requested fields
conv = api.get_object('me/conversations')
print(conv)
for el in conv['data']:
    print(el['id'])
    msg = api.get_object(el['id'] + '/messages')
    msg2 = api.get_object(el['id'])
    print(msg2)
    for el1 in msg['data']:
       content = api.get_object(el1['id'], **args)   #adding the field request
       print(content)
```

What's the best way to get the sender and receiver image and email ?

Thank you

Comment: What makes you think you should get access to their email?

Comment: I don't want to access their email. I want if some one message in my facebook page then I want the sender name, email and profile pic show in my app for analyzing.